# How do I display a mesh with curved lines?

Tags: mesh, interface

I sometimes see relatively low-poly meshes displayed with the lines between the nodes curving to the surface of what I assume to be a subsurfed form. I uploaded a few images to imgur that I found on google that indicate what I mean:

[image: an example]

Notice the line coming from the temple and curling around the ear, as well as the vertical lines on the back of the neck.

[image: another example]

Look at the vertical lines coming from below the armpits up across the pectoral muscles and the lines running from the shoulders down the arms at the spaces between the deltoids and biceps.

Hopefully, I'm communicating what I mean properly. Anyways, I wanted to know how I can enable these curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple to setup.

1)For curved edges in **object mode**: **Enable** **wire**, **show all edges** in **object data->** **display** and tick **optimal display** in Subd modifier.[image]

2) For curved edges in **Edit mode**: Enable **show in edit mode icon** (which is enabled in default) and then **enable show in cage icon** (triangular icon) in Subd modifier panel header.
[image]

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment: "Also, aside from the vague definitions given by the manual, what do 'draw all edges,' 'wire,' and 'optimal display' do individually?"

Comment: @thepufferfish when 'wire' enabled we can view all the edges over top of solid mesh.  I don't know why exactly, but 'wire' not always display all edges, it omits few edges if ngons and 5 pole vertices involved so enable 'draw all edges' ( you can see difference on suzane model if you want). They are not that much deal. High Subd mesh obstruct background images, other parts of mesh and view while modelling, so optimal display ensure to draw only required edges.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender, this is the result of checking 'Wire' and 'Show All Edges' in the Object tab > Display panel, while also checking 'Optimal Display' in a Subdivision Surface modifier.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally.. the 'all edges' or whatever the equivalent is, seems not to have been checked in the first example: an edge dividing a near-planar surface has not been displayed.

Comment: This seems to only work in object mode, I was hoping I could apply it in edit mode where I could edit the cage by moving the while more clearly seeing the resulting form.

Also, aside from the vague definitions given by the manual, what do 'draw all edges,' 'wire,' and 'optimal display' do individually?

Comment: @thepufferfish If the last two icons in the header of a subdivision surface modifier: 'Display in Edit Mode', and ’Adjust Cage to Result' are checked, the curves are displayed While editing.